# PHP date to string conversion is adding a minute to each result

Tags: php, date, laravel, format

I'm currently trying to display a 'time' entry from my database in PHP, and for some strange reason, it's displaying the time + 1 minute.

The entry is

```
'09:00:00'
```

And when my PHP code

```
$schedule = DB::table('event_sessions')->get();
foreach $schedule as $session {
    echo date( 'g:m A', strtotime($session->start_time)
}
```

it is displaying as

```
9:01 AM
```

Is there some configuration that might be wrong? I am using the Laravel framework and MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `m` is for the month in the `date()` function! (So if you want to use Minutes use `i` (e.g. `echo date( 'g:i A', strtotime("09:34"));` -> `09:34 AM`))

You also can do this:

```
echo date( 'g:m A', strtotime("09:34"));
```

And the return is:

```
09:01 AM
```

See the manual here for the `date()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

An a quote from the manual:

> m  Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12

Comment: Oh my goodness. I can't believe I'm so dumb, haha. Thank you so much.